# Is it possible to print in the margins with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I'm writing a web application that outputs PDFs.  The main content of my PDF is a table data.  I would like to make a message appear in the margins to the left and right of my table.

How can I do this, taking into account that the table will likely span several pages?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is probably to use Page Events. To use Page Events you need to subclass `PdfPageEventHelper`:

```
Public Class CustomPageEventHandler
    Inherits iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
End Class
```

The parent class has a bunch of methods that you can override, the one that you probably want is `OnStartPage()`. By overriding this, your custom code will get called for every page in the document.

```
Public Class CustomPageEventHandler
    Inherits iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
    Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, document As iTextSharp.text.Document)
        ''//Anything you do here will be done on every page
    End Sub
End Class
```

To bind your custom page event handler to a `PdfWriter` object called `writer` you'd just do:

```
writer.PageEvent = New CustomPageEventHandler()
```

As to what to do in the `OnStartPage()` method you've got a couple of choices. Unfortunately, working with the `Document` object itself will probably prove problematic. This object is meant as an abstraction for dealing with higher level concepts but doesn't always provide a way to do things at specific x,y coordinates. Using it here with text will just cause text to flow strangely.

Instead you'll want to work with a raw `PdfContentByte` object which you can get from the `writer`'s `DirectContent` property.

```
Dim cb = writer.DirectContent
```

Once you have that you've got a couple of options, I'll show you two. The first is to use a `ColumnText` object which you can pretty much think of as a table. In fact, most people use it as a single row, single column table. The `ColumnText` object is nice because it allows you to use the higher level abstractions such as `Paragraph` and it will automatically handle things like line breaks.

```
Dim CT As New ColumnText(writer.DirectContent)
CT.SetSimpleColumn(llx, lly, urx, ury) ''//Coordinates to draw text to
CT.AddElement(New Paragraph("This goes in the margin"))
CT.Go()
```

The second option is to just draw the text yourself. The biggest downside of this is that you can't work with the higher level abstractions like `Paragraph`. So if you draw a really long line of text it won't break it and start a new line for you, it will keep on drawing outside of the viewable document.

```
Dim cb = writer.DirectContent
cb.BeginText()
cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 8)
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED)
cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "right margin", x, y, 0)
cb.EndText()
```

Putting that all together, below is a full working VB.Net 2010 WinForm app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.2.0 that shows off all of the above. See the comments in the code for specific details.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.IO
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ''//Test file that we'll create
        Dim TestFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TestFile.pdf")
        ''//Standard PDF setup, change as needed for your stream type
        Using FS As New FileStream(TestFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            Using Doc As New Document(PageSize.LETTER)
                Using writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, FS)
                    ''//Bind our custom event handler to our writer object
                    writer.PageEvent = New CustomPageEventHandler()
                    Doc.Open()

                    ''//Add text on page 1
                    Doc.Add(New Paragraph("Page 1"))
                    ''//Add a new page
                    Doc.NewPage()
                    ''//Add text on page 2
                    Doc.Add(New Paragraph("Page 2"))

                    Doc.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    Public Class CustomPageEventHandler
        Inherits iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
        ''//This will get called whenever a new page gets added to the document
        Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, document As iTextSharp.text.Document)
            ''//Pre-calculate the Y coordinates for use later
            Dim yBot = document.PageSize.Height - 300
            Dim yTop = yBot + 200

            ''//For the left margin we'll use the ColumnText object
            Dim CT As New ColumnText(writer.DirectContent)
            ''//Create a single column object bound to our margin and using the y coordinates from above
            CT.SetSimpleColumn(0, yBot, document.LeftMargin, yTop)
            ''//Add a simple paragraph
            CT.AddElement(New Paragraph("This goes in the margin"))
            ''//Draw the text
            CT.Go()


            ''//For the right margin we'll draw the text manually
            ''//Grab the raw canvas
            Dim cb = writer.DirectContent
            ''//Store the current graphics state so that we can restore it later
            cb.SaveState()

            ''//Flag that we're begining text
            cb.BeginText()
            ''//Set a font and size to draw with
            cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 8)
            ''//Set a color for the text
            cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED)
            ''//Draw the text at a specific x,y coordinate. NOTE: These commands assume do not break text for you automatically
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "right margin", document.PageSize.Width - document.RightMargin, yTop, 0)
            ''//Flag that we're doing with our text
            cb.EndText()

            ''//Restore the graphics state to whatever it was before we started messing with it
            cb.RestoreState()


        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```